# How to count the number of polygons within a grid?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, vector-layer

I have two vector layers: 1) with polygons representing landcover types and 2) a grid, overlapped with the first one.

I want to obtain, for each square within the grid, the number of land cover types. For example: 
[image]

In the red square it would have 2 landcover types (2 and 7), and the left square to that one only 1 land cover type (2).

How do I obtain this values, using QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of polygons within your grid, you may use the **Join attributes by location** tool from the **Processing Toolbox**.

For your specific case, these parameters should work:

[image]

The output of the tool will be a grid layer which stores the number of the intersected polygons in a new field, called `"count"`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a virtual layer (layer > add layer > add/edit virtual layer)

Import both grid- and landcoverlayer

In the query-window you can add following code.  *In the code you will have to change grid, landcover and type to what your layers and attributes are named of.*

```
select grid.*, group_concat(landcover.type) as types from grid, landcover where st_intersects(grid.geometry, landcover.geometry)
```

Now you should get a new layer with a grid extended by an attribute called 'types'